# Pause scanner user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

really early stages of learning java so I apologize for my ignorance  but I've hit a bit of a snag. So I imported the scanner class, prompted user to input a number etc but now i cant seem to use the println command and I was wondering how to get back to normal so it's not taking in user input. Here is my code!

```
import java.util.Scanner;//Setting up scanner 

public class worksheet01 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num1;//declaring variable
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//for taking user input
            System.out.println("Hello user please enter a number"); //ask user to enter number
        num1 =in.nextInt();//Storing inputed value in num1
        if (num1 % 2==0) 
            System.out.println("The number is even");//If the number is even this will print out
        else 
            System.out.println("The number is odd");//If the number is odd this will print out
        Scanner .close();

            }   

    }
```

Comment: well first make sure you change `Scanner .close()` to `in.close()`, other than that try using `in.nextLine().parseInt()` instead of `nextInt()` and parsing int's out of the line in your if/else

Comment: As @beefoak pointed out, your code (as presented) won't compile.

Comment: The code works for me aside from where you close the Scanner object (should be `in.close()`

Comment: That worked! thank you very much people

Comment: One hint about commenting: you do not need to comment what the statement obviously does. For example, "// Setting up Scanner" on the import statement. These comments take time to read and it makes your code more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Turning `Scanner.close();` into `in.close()` should do the trick. This is because the `.close()` function only works with Scanner names. If you didn't name your scanner, *scanner*, then it won't work. In your code, you typed:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This shows that the Scanner is called *in*, so you should use `in.close()` instead of `Scanner.close();`.

**Your answer:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;//Setting up scanner 
public class test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int num1;//declaring variable
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//for taking user input
    System.out.println("Hello user please enter a number"); //ask user to enter number
    num1 = in.nextInt();//Storing inputed value in num1
    if (num1 % 2==0) {
      System.out.println("The number is even");//If the number is even this will print out
    } else {
      System.out.println("The number is odd");//If the number is odd this will print out 
    }
    in.close();
  }   
}
```